# OneDrive.js:2 Uncaught Error: [OneDriveSDK Error] invalid format for client id - AAD: 32 characters (HEX) GUID

Tags: onedrive

I get this when trying to show the OneDrive web picker. I'm 100% sure the client id is correct.

Comment: Could you show us your souce code?

Answer (score 1):

Just register you app in this page(https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList), it will generate a GUID type client id.